# The MySQL server is currently offline with the Cpanel error

Tags: mysql, cpanel

*Hi guys*, i am new to all this stuff and since this morning i found out one of our websites is down giving me this message:

> Could not connect to MySQL

In the CPanel I found this error in the section MySql databases:

> Error while connecting to MySQL: (XID 36chbf) nect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) Error while
>   connecting to MySQL: (XID 36chbf) nect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) at
>   /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Mysql.pm line 181.

Any suggestions? 
(one thought i had was that there is something wrong with the PHP version but I don't know where to start from)

Comment: Re your comments on the answer below: I think you should reboot your server as it seems various systems have crashed. If that doesn't help then open a Support Ticket with CPANEL.

Comment: I faced the same issue, do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a mysql connection error - double check all the details are correct and that the mysql instance is actually running.

Comment: How can i see if the instance is actually running?

Comment: Try accessing phpmyadmin, with your log in details directly through CPanel

Comment: $servername='localhost';

Comment: i changed it with

Comment: $servername='127.0.0.1'; and seems to work now but i dont know why

Comment: i also can't access php myadmin through cpanel :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after I had cPanel server SSL license issue.
But I have fixed that.
First you have to check the log file for mysql or mariadb.

Check the MySQL error logs: Access the MySQL error logs to get more information about the specific error that caused the service to fail. The location of the logs may vary depending on your server configuration. Typically, the MySQL error logs can be found in the '/var/log/mysql/' or '/var/log/mariadb/' directory. Look for any error messages that could provide insights into the problem.

In my case, log file path was /var/log/mysqld.log.

And I had this error:

```
2023-07-19T04:14:24.148474Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2023-07-19T04:14:24.148533Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2023-07-19T04:14:24.148873Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2023-07-19T04:14:25.024093Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2023-07-19T04:14:25.024456Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.42) starting as process 23236 ...
2023-07-19T04:14:25.027758Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2023-07-19T04:14:25.027790Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2023-07-19T04:14:25.027794Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-07-19T04:14:25.027799Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2023-07-19T04:14:25.027803Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2023-07-19T04:14:25.027806Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-07-19T04:14:25.028116Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-07-19T04:14:25.028256Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ib5n2yz2' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2023-07-19T04:14:25.028322Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
2023-07-19T04:14:25.028339Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2023-07-19T04:14:25.028349Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-07-19T04:14:25.028353Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-07-19T04:14:25.028357Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2023-07-19T04:14:25.028359Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

***There was an issue with creating a temporary file in the /tmp directory.***

The permissions should typically be set to 1777 or drwxrwxrwt. You can use the following command to check and set the permissions if needed:

```
ls -ld /tmp
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Different Linux distributions may use different service names for MySQL. Some common service names include mysqld, mysql, or mariadb. You can try restarting the service using one of these names. For example,

```
> sudo service mysqld restart
```

or

```
> sudo service mariadb restart
```